# How to get a string from a string, starting and ending with a specific string

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-4.5

I've got a string containing similar text like below

```
Name: John\n Surname: Smith\n Address: XXX\n
```

It can appear in different order.

I want to get the name value, the surname value and the adress value.

So the question is: how to get a string starting from string "Name: " and ending before "\n", so I get "John" and the code is very readable?

I tried to use the Substring function but it required modyfing the string so I get the correct index of the "\n" part. And I would prefer not to modify the original string so it's more readable.

Comment: *I tried to use the Substring function* - can you please add code which you have tried? And clarify what *It can appear in different order* means

Comment: What version of c#/.Net?

Comment: Easiest would be to use the `Split` method of the `String` class, using a delimiter `'\n'`.....

Comment: sure i'll add the code. @JoelCoehoorn its 4.5

Comment: Also: can the address field contain newline or colons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert this string to dictionary (i.e. set of key-value pairs). First split initial string by newline character into array of strings. Then each string from this array split by colon in two parts - key and value:

```
var input = "Name: John\n Surname: Smith\n Address: XXX\n";
var dictionary = input.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .Select(s => s.Split(':'))
                      .ToDictionary(p => p[0].Trim(), p => p[1].Trim());
```

And then read values by their keys:

```
var name = dictionary["Name"]; // gives you John
```

Note: if address or some other field is allowed to contain colon, you can use string.Join option from comment by @Joel Coehoorn when selecting value of dictionary.

Or you can use regex instead of splitting and joining strings. Just find pattern matches in your input:

```
var input = "Name: John\n Surname: Sm:ith\n Address: XX:X\n";
var dictionary = Regex.Matches(input, @"\s*([^:]+): ([^\n]+)\n").Cast<Match>()
                      .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
var address = dictionary["Address"]; // XX:X
```

Comment: For the value, maybe `string.Join(":", p.Skip(1).ToArray())`, to account for addresses or other items that might include a colon in the value.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn agree, address can contain colon `string.Join(":", p.Skip(1))` will do the job. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure where to use the "string.Join(":", p.Skip(1))" line

Comment: @QweRty in value selector instead of `p => p[1].Trim()` you should use `p => String.Join(":", p.Skip(1))`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Regex` in these type of situations for 2 reasons:

1. It is easier to maintain it in these situations. The `Substring`, `Split`, `Indexof` easily get convoluted when the role of the function increases.
2. It offers more flexibility for future changes

Below is the code to parse it:

```
static string ExtractParam(string input, string arg) {
    var match = Regex.Match(input, $@"\b{arg}:\s*(.*?)\n");
    return match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : null;
}

static void Main() {
    var input = "Name: John\n Surname: Smith\n Address: XXX\n";

    var name = ExtractParam(input, "Name");
    var surname = ExtractParam(input, "Surname");
    var address = ExtractParam(input, "Address");

    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name}\n Surname: {surname}\n Address: {address}\n");
}
```

The regex is very simple to understand.

```
\b   : Match a word boundary
\s*  : Eat up any unwanted whitespace
.*?  : Match any string in a non-greedy way
()   : Parenthesis are used to capture what we want to return
```